# Converting a bitstring into bytes(huffman coding)

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, compression, huffman-code

In huffman coding for decompression you have to compare a bitstream to several values(prefix free). I'm trying to implement a huffman coder decoder in python and this is my code to convert the bitstream into ascii-values.

```
c = ''
l = 0
x = 1
stime = time.time()
while l<len(string):
    if string[l:l+x] in table:
        c+=table[string[l:l+x]]
        l+=x
        x = 1
    else:
        x+=1
```

What could I do to make this loop more efficient?

Comment: what is `table`? Could you provide some input/expected output. Why do you think it is slow (have you profile the program)? How fast your version compared to [Huffman coding (Python)](http://en.literateprograms.org/Huffman_coding_(Python))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Fast:*

First off, make sure that you have built a canonical Huffman code, where the shorter codes come numerically before the longer codes.  This is done easily by first describing your Huffman code as simply the number of bits for each symbol.  Then assign Huffman codes to the shortest codes in symbol order, then the next shortest codes in symbol order, and so on.  E.g.

```
Symbol   Bits
  A        2
  B        4
  C        3
  D        3
  E        2
  F        3
  G        4
```

Sort by bits, retaining sort by symbol:

```
Symbol   Bits
  A        2
  E        2
  C        3
  D        3
  F        3
  B        4
  G        4
```

Assign Huffman codes, starting with zero:

```
Symbol   Bits    Code
  A        2     00
  E        2     01
  C        3     100
  D        3     101
  F        3     110
  B        4     1110
  G        4     1111
```

This canonical approach provides a compact means of transmitting a Huffman code from the compressor to the decompressor since you don't have to send the actual codes or a tree -- just the code lengths for each symbol.  Then the code can be built as above on the other end.

Now we create decoding tables, a symbol table, `Symbol[] = "AECDFBG"`, and a code index table:

```
Bits    Start     Index
  2    0000 (0)     0
  3    1000 (8)     2
  4    1110 (14)    5
```

Now to decode, you can loop from 2 to 4 bits, and see if your code is less than the starting code of the next bit size.  We pull four bits off the stream and call it `nyb` (if there aren't four more bits on the stream, just append with zero bits to fill it out).  In pseudo code using `if`'s instead of loop, and `>>` means shift bits down:

```
if nyb < Start[Bits are 3] (= 8) then
    output Symbol[Index[Bits are 2] (= 0) + (nyb - Start[Bits are 2] (= 0)) >> 2]
    remove top two bits from bitstream
else if nyb < Start[Bits are 4] (= 14) then
    output Symbol[Index[Bits are 3] (= 2) + (nyb - Start[Bits are 3] (= 8)) >> 1]
    remove top three bits from bitstream
else (must be four bits)
    output Symbol[Index[Bits are 4] (= 5) + (nyb - Start[Bits are 4] (= 14))]
    remove top four bits from bitstream
```

It should be pretty easy to see how to turn that into a loop, going from the shortest code length to the second longest code length, and if you come out without finding it, it must be the longest code length.

*Faster:*

Build a lookup table whose length is 2**(length of the longest code).  Each entry of the table contains the number of bits in the code, and the resulting symbol.  You take that many bits of the bitstream to use as an index.  Again, if the bitstream doesn't have that many bits left, then fill out with zeros.  Then you simply output the symbol from that indexed entry and remove the number of bits in that indexed entry from the bitstream (which may be less than the number of bits you pulled for the index -- make sure that you leave the unused bits in the bitstream).  Repeat, where now you are pulling off the first unused bits from the remaining bitstream.

At the next level of sophistication, you can do what [zlib](http://zlib.net/) does.  If the longest code is relatively long (in zlib it can be up to 15 bits), the time you take to make the table may not pay for the time saved in decoding, as compared to the following approach.  Have a two-level table, where the first level table covers up to `n` bits where `n` is less than the longest code.  (In zlib, the optimal choice turns out to be `n == 9` for a 15-bit code.)  Then if the code is `n` bits or less, the table entry provides the symbol and number of bits, and you proceed as above.  If the code is more than `n` bits, then you go to a sub-table for that `n`-bit value that processes the remaining bits, again as above.  That table entry indicates how many bits to pull for the sub-table, and defines the size of that sub-table, call it `k`.  You delete the top `n` bits from the stream and pull the next `k` bits and use that as an index to the sub-table.  Then you get the symbol and number of remaining bits in the code and proceed as in the single-level table.  Note that `n+k` is not necessarily the length of the longest code for each sub-table, since that sub-table may only cover shorter codes.  Only the last one or a few sub-tables will have `n+k` equal to the length of the longest code.

This can be quite fast since, by the construction of the Huffman code, the shorter codes are much more likely.  Most of the time you'll get the symbol at the first level, and only occasionally have to go the second level.  The total number of table entries to fill in in the main table and all of the sub-tables can be much less than the number of entries in a big table that covers the full code length.  The time spent preparing to decode is then reduced.

If you have even longer Huffman codes (e.g. 32 bits), you can have more levels of sub-tables.  It takes some experimentation to determine the optimal breakpoints for sub-tables, which will depend on how often a new code is sent and tables have to be built.

Answer (score 1):

You can make decoding faster if you are prepared to spend more time table-building, because you can build a set of tables so that you deal with the bitstream one byte at a time, and don't have to shift or mask the input stream to pick out individual bits.

You want to build a set of tables such that decoding a stream of bytes looks like this:

```
state = 0
for (input in inputBytes)
  output += outputTable[state][input]
  state = stateTable[state][input]
```

Here output will be a variable-length string of ascii values. State has to remember all the information from the previous byte or bytes that haven't turned into output data yet. One way to build these tables is to make state 0 the initial state - when you are just about to read the first byte of the input data. Then, for each bytes, decode as much of it as you can and use that to produce outputTable[0][byte]. Now look at all of the strings of unused bits at the end of the byte. For each of these strings you need to allocate a new state, and you need to do the same sort of table-building for each of these states, for all possible bytes. When you do this you end up with strings of unused bits after decoding, too. If these are bit strings you have already allocated states for you can ignore them and carry on. If not, you need to allocate more states. Eventually you will have built tables to cope with all possible states.

Comment: Wouldn't this take a massive amount of data? You could fit around 2-3 compressed characters into one byte that would equate to around a 16 meg dictionary.

Comment: 16 Mbytes doesn't sound big to me and I think you can do it in less than that. Each state corresponds to an interior node in the huffman tree so there should not be more than 256 states. Lets splash out on a 4-byte int to hold a state, say 8 bytes for a not very efficient string of output bytes so guess 16=2^4 bytes per entry times 2^8 entries times 2^8 states is 2^20 = 1 Mbyte.

Comment: This is a very inefficient approach, unless you are decoding an extremely long stream with a single Huffman code definition.  This is never the case for compressors I know of.  To make the compression efficient, a new Huffman code is periodically generated by all compressors to track the statistics of the data as it changes.  The approach described in my answer is efficient for such schemes, where it decodes only one symbol at a time -- not multiple symbols at a time, with the decoder left in one of many states in the middle of a code.  Building all the tables would dominate the decoding time.

Comment: There are a few cases where standard huffman codes are very often used - searching for evidence, at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG I find "The JPEG standard provides general-purpose Huffman tables; encoders may also choose to generate Huffman tables optimized for the actual frequency distributions in images being encoded." and see the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115155/jpeg-huffman-coding-procedure

Comment: The JPEG standard provides example Huffman codes, but does not require their use, nor is there a shorthand for using those codes in the data. The Huffman codes are always described in the JPEG data, and the decoder must use those code descriptions and construct what it needs to decode.  Furthermore, JPEG streams are usually relatively short, especially in their most common use on web pages, and so time spent building Huffman coding tables should be kept relatively low for the best overall decoding speed.