# Huffman minimum variance coding

Tags: algorithm, compression, proof, huffman-code

it is well known that Huffman code with minimum variance is preferable.
I've digged through entire Polish/English internet and this is what I found:
to build Huffman code with minimum variance you need to break ties with one of the following methods (of course probability of node is the most important):

- Select node that represents shortest tree
- Select node that was created earliest (consider leafs as created at start).

the problem is, that I couldn't find any proof of correctness of any of these methods.
Can someone proof any of these?

I will gladly clarify anything.

Comment: If you are after a mathematical proof, you might want to ask this at math.stackexchange.com or cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I don't know if I did the right thing, but I copied the question to math.stackexchange.com. Thanks for advice!

Comment: Huffman codes are codes minimizing the entropy, i.e. the bits per symbol. If several symbols have the same probability, it does not make any difference in terms of code efficiency how to resolve this tie. Huffman mentioned this in his his original paper. It is important, however, that encoder and decoder stick to the same tie-resolution strategy. I don't have a rigorous "proof", but what makes you doubt that the tie breaking rule could influence the resulting bitrate?

Comment: A general proof of the Huffman code optimality is here: http://www.cse.ust.hk/faculty/golin/COMP271Sp03/Notes/MyL17.pdf

Comment: You are not right. Let's give an example, you want to send encoded string over a network (with bandwidth 3kbit/s) and decode it in real-time. It's true that it doesn't matter how you break a tie in matter of average number of bits that are going to be sent. BUT, it does change variance of length of your code, so if yours average is 2.2kbit/s but your variance is high, then you can end up sending 1kbit/s (and not using all of available bandwidth) or 4kbit/s (and bandwidth will become a bottle neck). So, breaking ties method does matter as it can lower variance.

Answer (score 2):

Some systems have an even stronger constraint than 
"when there's a tie, make the choice that minimizes the maximum depth of a tree" --
they set a hard limit on the maximum depth of the tree ([length-limited, also called minimum variance Huffman coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding#Length-limited_Huffman_coding/minimum_variance_Huffman_coding)):

- "Whether there is a tie or not, build a tree with a maximum depth of at most 16 steps, so the maximum codeword length is 16 bits" (as in the [Huffman codes used in JPEG image compression](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JPEG_-_Idea_and_Practice/The_Huffman_coding))
  ( [Jpeg huffman coding procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115155/jpeg-huffman-coding-procedure) )
- "Whether there is a tie or not, build a tree with a maximum depth of at most 15 steps, so the maximum codeword length is 15 bits" (as in the [Huffman codes used in DEFLATE](https://zlib.net/feldspar.html) and the [Huffman codes used in gzip](https://www.daylight.com/meetings/mug00/Sayle/gzip2/tsld008.htm)
- "Whether there is a tie or not, build a tree with a maximum depth of at most 12 steps, so the maximum codeword length is 12 bits" (["Huff0 uses a 12-bit limit."](https://github.com/JoernEngel/joernblog/blob/master/engel_coding.md))

My understanding is that people have developed several [heuristic algorithms for limiting Huffman codeword lengths](http://cbloomrants.blogspot.com/2018/04/engel-coding-and-length-limited-huffman.html) that work OK, but the [heuristics don't always give exactly the best possible compression](https://fastcompression.blogspot.com/2015/07/huffman-revisited-part-3-depth-limited.html).

Several people mention "optimal length-limited Huffman codes", and apparently there exist more than one algorithm to find them:

- Lawrence L. Larmore and Daniel S. Hirschberg. ["A Fast Algorithm for Optimal Length-Limited Huffman Codes"](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~dan/pubs/LenLimHuff.pdf)
- ["Optimal Length-Limited Huffman Codes"](https://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/bitstream/10603/187253/9/09_chapter%204.pdf)
- ["A fast algorithm for optimal length-limited Huffman codes"](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=79150)